# use useEffect to respond to Redux state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, state, lifecycle

I need something to run every time a prop changes. With React classes, I could do:

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.x !== this.props.x) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

I know in hooks it should be `useEffect` with a dependency array:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // do something
}, [props.x])
```

But I need to do something outside of the useEffect scope.

In my case, I need a function within an `onChange` to run only when the Redux state has changed:

```js
const Editor: React.FC = () => {
  const { options } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.settings)

  <CodeMirror
    onChange={(editor, data, value) => {
    // I need to do something only when prev state is different
    if (prevOptions !== options) {
      editor.refresh()
    }
  />
```

I can't figure out how to do this, besides possibly setting a flag outside of the function component when a change happens and manually setting it back.

Comment: I think you should take a slightly different approach here. Looks like your goal is to refresh an editor whenever the state changes, so you're passing a reference to editor in onChange callback. How about creating an explicit reference in CodeMiror via React.useRef and run effect on that reference?

Comment: You're right, that would have worked, thanks! Turns out something wasn't working because of an ongoing CodeMirror bug anyway...thanks again.